# Querying, analyzing, and displaying data from external API in SharePoint

Tags: rest, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, api, azure-functions

I am a new SharePoint developer and I am tasked with displaying trends in data from Zendesk in SharePoint.  I have been reading the Microsoft documentations and from what I have been reading the result of the data I need to process will be displayed in a webpart in SharePointbut I am having issues seeing what the architecture that retrieves and processes the data will look like in the Microsoft ecosystem.

Does there have to be a separate application that calls the API, commits to a database, and sends data to the webpart for rendering or is there a different and particular way to do this in the Microsoft ecosystem?

I have also been looking into the Graph API and Azure web jobs but I am not understanding how these would fit into the architecture.

Please help me understand what the architecture of this would look like in the Microsoft ecosystem and if a separate application is required for the backend.